# A http request to google maps api direction with waypoints

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I'm working on an android app, using directions google maps api v2. It is said [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) that I can put, up to "8 waypoints" in my http request (I assume plus the origin and the destination points). So, my code generates the request below (I ordered it so you could count the number of waypoints).

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=45.509166,-73.497897&destination=5.5027,-73.503455&waypoints=optimize:true|
>   45.509196,-73.495494|
>   45.511166,-73.493584|
>   45.515887,-73.500751|
>   45.516835,-73.507189|
>   45.51497,-73.514892|
>   45.507828,-73.515879|
>   45.504038,-73.516008|
>   45.508971,-73.505665|
>   &sensor=false&API_KEY

This is the answer I get:

```
{
   "routes" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

Can one help me understand what is wrong? Does my request has an error, or I'm bypassing the limits of the direction google maps api?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]**may your url is missing something change with this new url**

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=45.509166,-73.497897&destination=50.5027,-73.503455&waypoints=optimize:true|45.509196,-73.495494|45.511166,-73.493584|45.515887,-73.500751|45.516835,-73.507189|45.51497,-73.514892|45.507828,-73.515879|45.504038,-73.516008|45.508971,-73.505665|&sensor=false&API_KEY

Comment: change destination=5.5027 with 50.5027

Comment: You are right. When I copy the location on google maps, it was supposed to be : 45.5027 not 5.5027. Again, thank you very much, I was there reviewing my code and debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly a guess, remove the optimization of waypoints? Wouldn't the optimization change where you have set them?

I do know you can use the Directions Response Elements to throw you some status codes to help debugging. "NOT_FOUND indicates at least one of the locations specified in the request's origin, destination, or waypoints could not be geocoded."

Comment: I tried with both true and false on optimization waypoints. The problem was about the waypoint that I didn't well copy paste as jitendra parmar stated. Again thank you.